# Windows Explorer has stopped working only when copying files

Tags: windows-7, windows

Since today I have the issue that when I want to copy a file, folder, icon, etc. anywhere on my computer or in an external drive i get the message "Windows Explorer has stopped working".

Right after this message appears the Windows Explorer is restarted.

The issue both happens if I copy the file by using the menu and ctrl+c. It does not happen when I cut and paste the file.

I restarted my computer, conducted sfc /scannow but nothing worked.

I use Windows7 64bit.

Do you have any idea how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Have you installed any new software recently? It sounds like there's a buggy shell copy hook.

Comment: See if disabling all 3rd party shell extensions (not just the 3rd party context menu handlers) helps. ([Shell extensions troubleshooting](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/slowrightclick.htm)) After disabling the extensions, logoff and login back for the changes to take effect.

Comment: capture a crash dump and share it (Onedrive, dropbox link). Here Are the steps to do this: pastebin.com/WACz5GBU I'll analyze it in the debugger

Comment: @w23sh: I downloaded the shell extansion but once I want to unzip the folder the explorer crashes the same way as it does when I copy a file. I guess it is because it also needs to copy a file within the extraction of the zip file.

Comment: @magicandre1981: When I download the file from your Onedrive and then I double click on it the webbrowser opens within the secure download manager but nothing more happens. Do I have to click something in the window? I also cannot find any data in the C:\Localdumps path.

Comment: run regedit.exe and import the file here